# wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) - method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why do i become such a error message ? 
Here's my controller:

```
#app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb
def upvote(user, post_id)
  @user=user
  @user.posts.find(post_id).increment!(:votes)
  redirect_to action: "view"
end
```

Here i use my function:

```
#app/views/dashboard/view.html.erb
<%=f.posts.find(i).votes%>, <%= link_to "+", upvote_dashboard_path(f,i) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller actions doesn't take any arguments, you pass any parameter into them with the use of `params` method. For example, your `upvote` link would look like this:

```
upvote_dashboard_path(user_id: f.id, post_id: i)
```

And you can access it in your controller with `params[:user_id]` and `params[:post_id]`.

Also, I **strongly** recommend you reading some Rails tutorials, as this is really basic Rails knowledge.

Comment: how do i take then any variables from outside in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not write controller `actions` like this.You have to write

```
def upvote
  @user= User find(params[:user_id])
  @user.posts.find(params[:post_id]).increment!(:votes)
  redirect_to action: "view"
end
```

and on the view part

```
#app/views/dashboard/view.html.erb
<%=f.posts.find(i).votes%>, <%= link_to "+", upvote_dashboard_path(user_id: f.id, post_id: i) %>
```